# In Spark's interactive shell, how to integrate conf param in spark context?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a newbie with Spark. In multiple examples seen on the net, we see something like:

```
conf.set("es.nodes", "from.escluster.com")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

but when I try in the interactive shell to do such a thing, I get the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)
```

So how am I supposed to set a conf parameter and be sure that sc "integrates" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options :

- call `sc.stop()` before this code
- Add --conf with your additional configuration as spark-shell argument

Comment: But suppose you have a large number of parameters to set, it's not very handy to have to specify all of them in the command line, is it? About sc.stop(), is it really the best practice? I mean, why do we see so many examples with conf.set followed by val sc = new SparkContext(conf) if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Patrick It works outside of `spark-shell`, where you have no instance of a `SparkContext` defined already